# Why do we sometimes refer to the solar wind as young solar wind?

Tags: terminology, history, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind

Why do we sometimes refer to the solar wind as *young solar wind*? What does *young* imply?

Comment: Who are the "we"? Perhaps you could give a reference to a place where it is called that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of articles such as [this one](https://phys.org/news/2019-10-microsatellites-never-before-seen-young-solar.html) “young solar wind” means the solar wind that is relatively close to the sun’s photosphere, within or just outside the solar corona.

> As the young solar wind flows through the corona, its behavior is still dominated by the Sun's magnetic fields. But once it escapes the corona, its behavior changes.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure this is correct.  That is, the term young is often used in the context of collisional age.  The younger the solar wind, the lower the collisional age, the more likely the observed distributions are to deviate from any idea of thermal or thermodynamic equilibrium.